# FirefoxDriver cannot be cast to HasInputDevices

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium FirefoxDriver. I want to drag and drop some elements on html page, so I'm using:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(firefoxDriver)
```

But I got this exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver cannot be cast to
>   org.openqa.selenium.interactions.HasInputDevices.

Any ideas?

Comment: How have you defined `firefoxDriver`? Also, show the `Actions` import line.

Comment: WebDriver firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver(); ... Actions builder = new Actions(webDriver);
        Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(from).moveToElement(to).release(to).build();
        dragAndDrop.perform();

Comment: import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

Comment: What version of selenium and firefox are you using? Try the latest of both.